# Is there a way to auto-tag long and short questions?

Tags: feature-request

Usually long questions are from people who are very detailed or very confused.  Due to their length people are less inclined to read them and answer them.  But there are also people who prefer these questions.

Should stackoverflow automatically tag questions over a certain length as "long-question" perhaps not taking code snippets or edits into account when determining length?  This would also help those who don't want to see long questions.

Answer (score 2):

Er, no.. It's not exactly difficult to look at the question at decided if you can be bothered to read it or not..

All this would do is make less people view questions they may be able to answer. It would also make people less likely to put time and effort into good, comprehensive questions (*"if I add any more words to my question, it'll get marked as 'long' and no one will look at it!"*)

Answer (score 2):

> Due to their length people are less inclined to read them and answer them.

I don't entirely agree with you there; whilst some long answers *can* be a deterrent from reading, if it's on a topic that I'm interested in or have the ability to answer, I'll read it; sometimes these are the better questions, in fact, since:

1. They can be more detailed than shorter questions, and less ambiguous and actually make sense compared to some very short, or shorter questions.
2. Often the longer questions are more specific than other questions that are popular and everyone goes in to answer, so I'm more likely to get a good answer in than in a popular question that lots of people know the answer to.
3. They can often be more thought-out than shorter questions where the user has asked a simple question without doing a search beforehand, so can be more interesting.

Therefore I don't think it's necessary to tag questions as either long or short, because long and short questions can both be good or bad.